# Resize image without lose quality when image is bigger then 3000px

Tags: php

i have script to resize my upload image without losing quality but when its about more then 3000 pixels wide/hight it dont resize. I try to set values in httaccess but nothing changes.
**Here is the script:**

```
$filename = "image.jpg";
    // Set a maximum height and width
    $width = 490;
    $height = 800;

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

    $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;

    if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
    }

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, "image_resized.jpg", 100);
```

**and .htacces i tried:**

```
php_value memory_limit 24M
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M  
php_value post_max_size 10M  
php_value max_input_time 300  
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: White screen with no image, nothing else, image is upload but in original size

Comment: Can you try a `var_dump(imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig));exit;` to check the return value?

Answer (score 2):

In Resampling the image use @

i.e.

```
// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
```

TESTED SOLUTION.